# how can I implement types on classes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typescript-typings

I have this basic class:

```
type Action = { type: string; payload?: {} }
type Dispatch<ActionType extends Action> = (action: ActionType) => void


type Actions = 
  |  { type: '@ADD', payload: { item: string, id: string } }
  |  { type: '@REM', payload: { id: string } }

class CardActions implements ActionClass<Actions> { // this isn't working as I expect, see below
  constructor(private dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>) {}

  disp(action) {} // this isn't working
}
```

trying to implement an interface didn't work neither for the constructor nor the `disp` function, it always has the error:

> Index signature is missing in type 'CardsActions'

or

> Class 'CardActions' incorrectly implements interface 'ActionClass'.

```
export interface ActionClass<ActionType extends Action> {
  // new(dispatch: string): any;
  [actionKey: string]: (action: ActionType['type']) => void
}
```

I'm expecting it to work like any function, did I misunderstand it?

**Expectation**

```
interface Func {
  (action: Actions['type']): void
}

const func: Func = (action) => {} // this will work
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=18&ssc=1&pln=19&pc=1#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)

why they don't work like eachother? and how can I make it work?

Comment: Are you really expecting a string index signature and a call signature to behave the same?  That is, do you expect to be able to call an instance of `CardActions` as if it were a function?  If not, can you elaborate on why you think they should be the same?  If you remove everything in the question starting with "I'm expecting it to work like any function, did I misunderstand it?", I can answer why it's not working.  But I'm not sure what you are getting at by likening a class or a class instance to a function.

Comment: You also have `// new(dispatch: string): any;` in there, commented out.  What are you doing with that and why is it part of your question?  If you comment it in it won't work because in `class Foo implements Bar {}`, the type `Bar` corresponds to *instances* of `Foo`, not the `Foo` constructor itself.  Instances of `Foo` won't be constructible, so you don't want a construct signature in `Bar`.  Without something like [ms/TS#33892](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33892), there's no way to constrain the static side of a class with `implements`.

Comment: I've answered the question as if `// new(dispatch: string): any;` and everything starting with `I'm expecting it to work like any function` were not present.  If you need something else, please modify the question and elaborate on these points.  Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I just meant with the expectation, why don't we have class methods as functions, not each time we will declare a new one we will have to add the type, and I would prefere the approach of having a definition type then I adjust when necessary, that's what I meant by the example of the function, is this a limitation of typescript?

Comment: Yes it’s a limitation; see my answer below and the section that starts “One current limitation”, and the linked GitHub issue.

Comment: Yup, thank you again straight to the point, my problem been solved. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this answer I will use a slightly modified version of `ActionClass` that removes the generics, as they are not relevant to the particular issue you're running into:

```
interface ActionClass {
  [actionKey: string]: (action: Actions['type']) => void
}
```

---

One current limitation of TypeScript is that when a `class` implements an `interface`, the compiler does not use the definition of the interface to [contextually type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) the members of the class.  In `class Foo implements Bar {...}`, the compiler will infer a type for `Foo` without consulting `Bar` at all; and only afterward will it check that type against `Bar`.  See [microsoft/TypeScript#32082](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32082) and the many linked issues within to read more about this.

For now, if you want `class Foo implements Bar {...}` to work, you will need to manually and explicitly give `Foo`'s members everything the compiler needs so that the inferred type of `Foo` is assignable to `Bar`.

Right now `CardActions` is inferred as if you wrote this:

```
class CardActions {
  constructor(private dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>) { }
  disp(action) { }
}
```

Because you did not give `CardActions` an [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), the compiler does not infer one. So then `CardActions` is not seen as assignable to `ActionClass`, which does have one:

```
class CardActions implements ActionClass { // error
  constructor(private dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>) { } 
  disp(action) { }
}
```

Additionally, the `action` parameter of `disp()` is inferred as `any` because the compiler does not consult `ActionClass` at all, and you didn't annotate `action`.

So the first steps to a fix here would be to give `CardActions` an explicit index signature, and give the `action` parameter of `disp()` an explicit type:

```
class CardActions implements ActionClass {
  constructor(private dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>) { } // error
  [actionKey: string]: (action: Actions['type']) => void;
  disp(action: Actions['type']) { }
}
```

Now we have a new error.

---

Note that `ActionClass` has a string index signature.  That means *all* properties of an `ActionClass` object must be a function of the type `(action: Actions['type']) => void`.  But in your constructor, you have put the `private` keyword on the `dispatch` parameter, making it a [*parameter property*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#parameter-properties).  That's shorthand for something like:

```
class CardActions implements ActionClass {
  private dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>; // error
  constructor(dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>) {
    this.dispatch = dispatch;
  }
  [actionKey: string]: (action: Actions['type']) => void;
  disp(action: Actions['type']) { }
}
```

And here's your problem.  The `dispatch` property is of type `Dispatch<Actions>`, but the index signature requires that every property be assignable to `(action: Actions['type']) => void`.  And a `Dispatch<Actions>` is not assignable to that (the parameter type is wrong).

I'm not sure what the right way to fix this is, since I'm not sure whether you really want the index signature as written or you really want a `dispatch` property.  But you can't have both without an error.  Let's remove the `dispatch` property just to see that the error goes away:

```
class CardActions implements ActionClass {
  constructor(dispatch: Dispatch<Actions>) { }
  [actionKey: string]: (action: Actions['type']) => void;
  disp(action: Actions['type']) { }
}
```

Hooray, no error!  There are probably a hundred different possible approaches that one might want to take instead of this, but exploring those is probably out of scope for this question.

---

So there you go.  If you want a class to implement an interface that has a string index signature, you need to explicitly declare the index signature in the class definition, and you need to make sure that every single known  property of the class is compatible with the index signature.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=48&ssc=2&pln=47&pc=1#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-tUVCoxIAhDi4IG4AAFUOwKiQOBFF2e+RFODoLzdWDJxmu73xdkZ6RwTDoMBwLWoOivABGSKI6HuGxm2nUOfgRQFBjIACIBkM+x04AOTqc+xUqi4igA6S2R2K5JIpFvLLJmOK9k2w4qlcr2OBOFwMSMuntWHd4vdNMpC7nC0BiyVvD6sWVwBVK7THACO+NQBxVTaTUwR1aEWnhRFkS0Y1WTNMEInVKIyUAp1qQ9Zl3SZL09UMJhoxgENiUjb8CSJElUywuB8zTQtYV9JDLSiMB5GkWcqIUExOPkU9kOFS0l3iFd1nXbIt0vPUb1gO9D2Pbg+Mtc8JLyK82WkmBZK5NoxTFUDtUhCCixmA0YNRdFcgQ7F1TIm0KNMHjsILPD7zaISDBEtdMnE3J8iLDTZMqI9qkUjD+RUvzdxKW8D208U1XcVEiJ8D9vnxTAkAtTdfLUwpopk8oyHkp9QFsuAvHSpAyDSjKTAvTApz9KMg3QABrNhQAqjLTAHQYJEnAiWvaiAGiAA)

Comment: Why not a union type with `Dispatch<Actions>`? I believe that's one of the [options the manual recommends](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/index-signatures#having-both-string-and-number-indexers). Edit: Not the manual... I see...

Comment: Sure, that's one approach.  There are lots of ways to proceed but without the desired use case it's all speculative.